# How to track coding time by only using git data?

Tags: git

I have to track my coding time measured by minutes, but git only can record the committed date.

Is it possible to track my coding time by only using git data(e.g commit, gblob)?

There is a plugin, [gtm](https://github.com/git-time-metric/gtm), can be used, but it capture activity triggered by the editor.

Comment: I think that the answer is that you can't.

Comment: Not that this *can't* be done by other means, but git is just not the tool for that.

Comment: Git records every commit by the seconds.

Comment: The commit date and author date can be easily forged. They are not reliable at all.